# Creating events for a buttons programmatically in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I have an array of jbuttons. I wanted to add `Home_MouseDown` procedure, to the mousePressed event of the jbutton. Below is the array of JButton that I created.

Code:

```
    Jbutton[][] home = new JButton[8][8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {                
            home[j][i] = new JButton();

            this.add(home[j][i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?/What have you tried?

Comment: Why does Home start with capital? Is it a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Home[j][i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

   @Override
    ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
   //w.e function u wanna add here on mouse click
    }
    });
```